# Topological vector spaces and Neighbourhood bases at 0

Tags: general-topology

Topological vector spaces have just been introduced to my class doing early functional analysis. They define a $\textit{topological vector space} $ (TVS) as a vector space $X$ over $\mathbb{K}$ together with a Hausdorff topology $\tau$ s.t. the mappings
$$(x,y)\in X\times X\rightarrow x+y\in X,\quad (\lambda,x)\in \mathbb{K}\times X\rightarrow \lambda x \in X
$$
are both continuous. Then the author casually lets us know that the topology $\tau$, making the space a Hausdorff space, is well-defined by a neighbourhood base $(U_a)_{a\in I}$ at $0$ satisfying
$$\cap_{a\in I}U_a=\{0\}
$$
In other words; the above condition ensures that the topology $\tau$ truely is Hausdorff.

Why is this true? I don't mean to be ungrateful and ask for the answer without having put any effort into it myself, but I am not sure how to approach proving this. I know what being Hausdorff mean, and the definition of a neighbourhood basis.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \neq y$. Then $x-y \neq 0$ so there exists $a$ such that $x-y \notin U_a$. Now there exists a symmetric neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $V+V\subseteq U_a$. You can now see that $x+V$ and $y+V$ are neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ which are disjoint.

Comment: Minor addition: the existence of $V$ follows from the continuity of addition (and negation).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you. That is what I had in mind, but wasn't being very explicit.